# Wake notebook from sleep with USB4 wake-on-connect

Tags: suspend, sysfs, dock-station

I have a Lenovo T16 Gen 2 notebook with two thunderbolt 4 ports and a docking station. A usb keyboard is connected to the dock. I switch the connection of the dock between two notebooks. I want to turn on the Lenovo notebook without having to open the lid.

If I put the notebook to sleep, I am able to wake it up by pressing a key on the external keyboard. Though if I unplug and replug the dock this wakeup method does not work anymore.

Reading this article I discovered that there is an option to turn on the notebook when something is connected to the TB4/USB4 port.
https://www.phoronix.com/news/USB4-Wake-On-Connect-Linux-6.2

I enabled the wakeup as specified in the article, like this:

```
/sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/0-0/usb4_port1/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/0-0/usb4_port3/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/1-0/usb4_port1/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/thunderbolt/devices/1-0/usb4_port3/power/wakeup:enabled
```

Still the wakeup does not work when I try to plug the docking station in one of the ports. I also tried to plug the keyboard directly but still does not work.

Any idea on what else can I try?